# Prevent router to clear URL parameters from address bar in Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-params

In angular 12, when I am trying to navigate to a route along with query parameters, I am able to get the values of those parameters but they are getting cleared from the url.

I am using the below code to navigate:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  query: any;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onEnterSearch() {
    this.router.navigate(['/portal'], {queryParams: { q: this.query }})
  }

}
```

I am getting the URL params like this in the navigated component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-portal',
  templateUrl: './portal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portal.component.scss']
})
export class PortalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((paramMap: any) => {
      console.log(paramMap.get('q'))    // successfully getting the value
    });
  }
}
```

For a second my url appears like : `http://localhost:4200/portal?q=querytext`

But then it get cleared to : `http://localhost:4200/portal`

I want to retain my URL in the browser's address bar.
Not sure why it is getting cleared.

**NOTE**

`this.router.navigate(['/portal'], { queryParams: { q: this.query }, queryParamsHandling: 'merge'})`

OR

`this.router.navigate(['/portal'], { queryParams: { q: this.query }, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'})`

these parameters didn't help.

**Update**

Saved parameters are also getting lost

**Update 2**

Here's how I setup my routes

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { PortalComponent } from './components/portal/portal.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'portal',
    component: PortalComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you set up your [routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#:~:text=The%20following%20route%20specifies%20that%20when%20navigating%20to)?

Comment: I updated my routes in question.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce what you mentioned from the code you provided. There must be something else in your `app.component.ts` file or some root file that messing with you. Your best bet is to create a small project with code you provided and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: @DeskOfDev Where is `onEnterSearch()` called? Where is `this.query` set? 
Also, have you tried using `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('q')` instead of subscribing?